# Custom command with predefined argument

Tags: macros

I was wondering how to create a custom command that works something like this:

```
\mycommand{1} = blue
\mycommand{2} = red
\mycommand{3} = yellow
```

where any other argument causes an error.
Basically, I want to "switch" on the argument, so that each argument has one predefined outcome.
I tried doing something like Haskell's pattern-matching,
and I have looked at various key-value packages but haven't been able to get a solution from them.

Im sorry if this doesn't make sense, I'm not entirely sure how to put this problem into words.

Comment: Will your "predefined argument" be numeric or string?

Comment: This is pretty vague. Can yo give more details as to what you want. Currently `\mycommand` does not do anything. You wat it to accept only `1`, `2`, `3` as valid arguments or `blue`, `red`, `yellow`. pgfkeys, for example, will certainly throw errors if  it does not recognise a key

Comment: string
And I want it to accept 1,2,3 as arguments, as an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mycommand[1]{%
  \ifcsname foo\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
      \csname foo\detokenize{#1}\expandafter\endcsname
   \else
     \PackageError{mypackage}{go away: \detokenize{#1} not defined}{really}%
   \fi}



\expandafter\newcommand\csname foo1\endcsname{ONE}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname foo2\endcsname{TWO}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname foo3\endcsname{THREE}

\begin{document}

\mycommand{2}

\mycommand{0}

\mycommand{a}

\mycommand{\section+\cos\usepackage}

\end{document}
```

the above gracefully accepts any argument, making errors such as

```
! Package mypackage Error: go away: \section +\cos \usepackage  not defined.

See the mypackage package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.24 \mycommand{\section+\cos\usepackage}

?
```

Comment: What if, instead of displaying a string, I want to perform another command, like `\includegraphics{}`?

Comment: @MattG just write `\includegraphics{..}` instead of `TWO` it makes no difference to TeX what is in the replacement text of a command.

Answer (score 2):

So here's an example which uses `l3keys` from [`expl3`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3).  The key `somekey` is defined to take a number of choices and will throw an error if the argument of `\mycommand` is not one of the pre-defined choices.  The argument of `\mycommand` is then taken as the value given to the key `somekey`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mattg } {
    somekey .choice:,
        somekey / 1.code:n = { Blue },
        somekey / two .code:n = { Red },
        somekey / three .code:n = { Yellow },
    somekey .value_required:n = true 
}

\NewDocumentCommand \mycommand { m } {
    \keys_set:nn { mattg } { somekey = #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\mycommand{1}
\mycommand{two}
\mycommand{three}
%The argument foo is unrecognised (not being one of the pre-defined choices) and thus throws an error
\mycommand{foo}
\end{document}
```